# Parallel processing of MongoDB data. Data collision

Tags: mongodb, parallel-processing

I use mongodb DB.

**The problem**: There are `n` parallel processes, each of them takes documents with query `{data_processed: {$exists: false}}`, processes them and updates setting {data_processed: true}. When I run all `n` processes, sometimes the same document appears on two or more different processes.

I think I can use something like this on query to prevent collision.

```
each process have id from 1 to n
for process with id i, get these documents
{
  data_processed: {$exists: false},
  _id: {mod_n: i}
}
where mod_n is Modulo operation on i
```

I use bson default ObjectId as _id, so I think it is possible to do something like this.

How can I implement this query ? Or can you suggest better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there's no easy way to convert `ObjectId` to long to perform modulo operation. Alternatively you can distribute your processing using simple string comparison for last character of `_id` or few last characters if you need more threads,

For instance if you want to run your processing using `4` processes you can try following queries:

```
db.col.aggregate([ { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ { $substr: [ { $toString: "$_id" }, 23, 1 ] }, [ "0", "1", "2", "3" ]  ] } } } ])
...
db.col.aggregate([ { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ { $substr: [ { $toString: "$_id" }, 23, 1 ] }, [ "c", "d", "e", "f" ]  ] } } } ])
```

This can scale to a higher number of processes, if you need more than `16` just take last two characters like:

```
db.col.aggregate([ { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ { $substr: [ { $toString: "$_id" }, 22, 2 ] }, [ "00", "01" ]  ] } } } ])
```

Load should be distributed more or less evenly since last three characters represent

> 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

Comment: Thank You. Just one question. Is it better to find all docs, then process on the project. for example, I can find all docs, then filter it with javascript, say `docs = db.col.find(...).filter(i => i.id.endswith('0') )`. I think this way we can use indexes too.

Comment: @Gor it depends on your architecture, if your processes need to be independent then it's better to do that on the database layer, if you have some shared memory then you can pull that data and distribute this processing in-memory but I'd prefer database-level filtering